# How to handle args in yarn CLI that calls multiple scripts

Tags: command-line-interface, yarnpkg

Let's say I have a yarn script that's set up like this:

```
// package.json
{
  ...
  "scripts": {
    "custom": "script1 && script2"
  }
}
```

If `script1` requires some additional arguments, how would I pass them?

Running `yarn custom -- --foo=bar` would trigger `script1 && script2 --foo=bar` as opposed to the intended `script1 --foo=bar && script2`.

Comment: Just looking for the same answer. Did you find one?